# Remove N/A from the Data Frame

Tags: r, na

Data frame is like
[image]

Where i have to remove the rows having atleast one N/A in any column of data frame.

Tried These

```
   frame1 <- na.omit(frame1)
   is.null(frame1)
   [1] FALSE
```

Guess there's a difference between NA and N/A
How can i remove the rows as explained

Comment: Im guessing NA is the R's built in and "N/A" is a string coming from your dataset? Can you show your raw data ?

Comment: Yes "N/A" might coming from the website directly to the data frame

Comment: so turn your string values "N/A" into R's `NA`first

Comment: @akrun No, it hasn't been answered.  The OP has imported the characters, "N/A" rather than the R values of NA.  I was just typing a solution ... please re-open.

Comment: @user1945827  Okay, reopened, the link was provided by Sotos, which i tagged

Comment: Call your data DF: `DF[,] <- sapply(DF,function(x) gsub("N/A",NA,x))` then use `complete.cases`

Comment: @akrun thanks.  Of course the OP will most probably not acknowledge the answer.

Comment: you can use `na.strings = "N/A"`,while reading and then use `complete.cases`

Comment: You just really need to read the data correctly (as mentioned by @vdep)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
A  <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4),
                 y=c(1,2,3,4),
                 z=c(1,"N/A",3,4))

A[A == "N/A"]  <- NA
na.omit(A)
```

The trick is to change your character values, "N/A" to what R understands to be NA.

Comment: the last line can also be replaced by A[ which( complete.cases(A)) ,  ]

Comment: @user1945827 But in my dataframe I'm getting this error `Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`